# Prolog delete all increasing subseries from a list

Tags: list, prolog, series

The task is to delete all increasing subseries from a list. For example:
`deleteInc([2,4,6,5,8,12,8,3],L)` should produce  `L=[8,3]` as result

I tried to solve it, but it's not working properly and I can't figure out the correct solving. Can somebody help me out please with a correct solution? Thanks in advance :)

My Code:

```
deleteInc([],[]).
deleteInc([H1,H2|T],L):-
    H2>=H1,
    !,
    deleteInc(T,L).
deleteInc([H1,H2|T],[H2|T2]):-
    H2<H1,
    deleteInc(T,T2).
```

Comment: Can you explain more, what do you mean by subseries? and what kind of output are you expecting?

Comment: For the given input the first increasing subsieres is 2,4,6 then it's followed by 5,8,12 which is also an increasing subseries, and after that there are the 8,3 numbers which are not increasing so the result is 8,3.

Comment: Is it checking 3 values at a time? [2,4,6], then [5,8,12] ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Here's what I did, assuming it's checking three values at a time:

```
deleteInc([],[]).
deleteInc([H1,H2,_H3|T],L):-
    H2>=H1,
    !,
    deleteInc(T,L).
deleteInc([H1,H2|T],[H1,H2|T2]):-
    H2<H1,!,
    deleteInc(T,T2).
```

**Example:**

```
?-deleteInc([2,4,6,5,8,12,8,3],L).
L = [8, 3]

?-deleteInc([2,4,6,5,8,12,15,21,25,7,3],L).
L = [7, 3]

?-deleteInc([2,4,6,5,8,12,15,21,25,55,77,88,65,38],L).
L = [65, 38]
```

---

Here's an approach to collect all combinations that are not increasing:

```
deleteInc(L,[],L).
deleteInc([H1,H2|T],L,Rest):-
    H2>=H1,
    !,
    deleteInc(T,L,Rest).
deleteInc([H1,H2|T],[H1,H2|L],Rest):-
    H2<H1,!,
    deleteInc(T,L,Rest).
```

**Example:-**

```
?-deleteInc([2,4,6,5,8,12,15,21,25,55,77,88,65,38],L,_).
L = []
L = []
L = [6, 5]
L = [6, 5]
L = [6, 5]
L = [6, 5]
L = [6, 5]
L = [6, 5, 65, 38]

?-deleteInc([2,4,6,5,8,12,15,21,25,7,3],L,_).
L = []
L = []
L = [6, 5]
L = [6, 5]
L = [6, 5]
L = [6, 5, 25, 7]

?-deleteInc([2,4,6,5,8,12,8,3],L,_).
L = []
L = []
L = [6, 5]
L = [6, 5]
L = [6, 5, 8, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would implement it like this:

```
deleteInc(In, Out):-
    deleteInc(In,Out,new).

deleteInc([A],[A],new).
deleteInc([_],[],incr).
deleteInc([H1,H2|T],L,_):-
    H2>=H1,
    !,
    deleteInc([H2|T],L,incr).
deleteInc([H1,H2|T],T2,incr):-
    H2<H1,
    deleteInc([H2|T],T2,new).
deleteInc([H1,H2|T],[H1|T2],new):-
    H2<H1,
    deleteInc([H2|T],T2,new).
```

A third attribute indicates if your are currently in a `new` or `incr`easing streak.

If the two head elements of the list are in increasing order, the third element is pretty much ignored. Please note to forward not the list `T` but `[H2|T]` since you need the element `H2` for further comparison. If you are in a streak (`incr`) and the current two head elements are not increasing, you do the same as before: ignore. However if you just started a `new` streak and the current head elements are decreasing, you put the first head element in the return list. Special cases for one element. Let's check:

```
?- deleteInc([2,4,6,5,8,12,8,3],L).
L = [8, 3] ;
false.
```

Looks good.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to just check for 3 succeeding elements if the middle one is smaller than the first but larger than the third. If this is the case: store the element. If this is is not the case: check the list without the first head element.

Add a rule for 2 elements left. Also there needs to be a special treatment for the very first element, because this is not covered in the main rule. By using the cut you can "catch" the left over case (two increasing elements or weird input with one or no element) with the last line. Please note that the order of the rules is important for the program to work.

```
deleteInc([H1,H2|L], [H1|R]):-
    H1 >= H2,
    !,
    deleteInc1([H1,H2|L], R).
deleteInc([H1,H2|L], R):-
    deleteInc1([H1,H2|L], R).

deleteInc1([H1,H2,H3|L], [H2|R]):-
    H1 > H2,
    H2 > H3,
    !,
    deleteInc1([H2,H3|L], R).
deleteInc1([A,B],[B]):-
    A > B,
    !.
deleteInc1([_|L], R):-
    !,
    deleteInc1(L, R).
deleteInc1(_,[]).
```

Let's test it:

```
?- deleteInc([2,4,6,5,8,12,8,3],L).
L = [8, 3].
```

Works (for lists of numbers).

Answer (score 1):

And yet another solution would be to count the length of the streak and to filter out all results which have more than one element. The following code starts with count 0 for the first element and uses the successor predicate `s/1` for counting:

```
deleteInc(In, Out):-
    countInc(In,0,InC),
    delInc(InC,Out).

countInc([A], C, [(A,C)]).
countInc([A,B|L], C, Out):-
    A =< B,
    countInc([B|L], s(C), Out).
countInc([A,B|L], C, [(A,C)|Out]):-
    A > B,
    countInc([B|L], 0, Out).
    
delInc([],[]).
delInc([(E,0)|L],[E|R]):-
    delInc(L,R).
delInc([(_,s(_))|L],R):-
    delInc(L,R).
```

Output:

```
?- deleteInc([2,4,6,5,8,12,8,3],L)
L = [8, 3] ;
false.
```

As expected